# Change drawable color of the background of imageView using seekbar

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-seekbar

I am trying to develop an application that can animate something like using knob to change light intensity and color in daily life.

My thought is that using drawable as background of a bulb imageview and then changing the color and radius of radial gradient by using seekbar to replace knob to archive this animation. In my partial implementation, I try to change the color when the seekbar is changed but it did not show up any change.

My code is as below, can anyone help? Thank you.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SeekBar intensity;
String colorChange;
ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
ShapeDrawable mDrawable2;
ImageView bulb;
RadialGradient radialGradient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    radialGradient = new RadialGradient(300,300,240,
            Color.YELLOW,Color.TRANSPARENT,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setShader(radialGradient);
    bulb = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bulb);
    bulb.setBackground(mDrawable);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    intensity = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.intensity);
    intensity.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            radialGradient = new RadialGradient(300,300,240,
                    Color.BLUE,Color.TRANSPARENT,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            mDrawable.getPaint().setShader(radialGradient);
            bulb.setBackground(mDrawable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
    });


}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/backLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bulb_top"
        android:id="@+id/bulb"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/intensity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you dont use `int progress` in any way, so what would change?

Comment: I have not use the progress value to change the color yet, I simply want to test when I move around the seekbar, the color will change from yellow to blue.